# Erro na hora de adicionar referência a um Web Service

Tags: web-service

Estou tentando adicionar um referência a um Web Service dentro do meu projeto pelo Visual Studio e recebo este erro:

> There was an error downloading 'http://sigep.correios.com.br/sigep/update/AtendeClienteService.wsdl/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
>   The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.

Eu adiciono o endereço que esta online pelo navegador: http://sigep.correios.com.br/sigep/update/AtendeClienteService.wsdl

Estou seguindo o passo a passo desse site:

https://ehrizo.wordpress.com/2014/12/04/correios-webservice-para-consulta-de-enderecos-a-partir-de-um-cep/

Obrigado

Comment: Mauricio, adiciona mais informações quanto ao seu problema. Informa em qual linha tá dando problema, mostra seu código que talvez assim fique mais fácil de te ajudar.

Comment: Então nao tem código, em modo visual dentro do Visual Studio eu preciso adicionar uma referência a esse WebService mas quando eu clico em adicionar ele retorna esse erro. Eu consigo adicionar um print da tela aqui no post?

Comment: Sim, consegue. Também não consegui adicionar a referência. Estranho...

Comment: O HStackOverflow conseguiu me ajudar. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez o endereço tenha mudado, tente este:

https://apps.correios.com.br/SigepMasterJPA/AtendeClienteService/AtendeCliente?wsdl

Testes feitos aqui funcionou:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você conseguiu pelo Visual Studio dentro do projeto?

Comment: Desculpa fiz confusão, vou testar novamente. Vou editar ou remover a resposta.

Comment: Certo aguardo seu retorno. Obrigado

Comment: Editei com o endereço atualizado. Teste feito com sucesso.

Comment: Vou testar. Obrigado

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Tentei adicionar o seguinte EndPoint como Service Reference:

> http://sigep.correios.com.br/sigep/update/AtendeClienteService.wsdl

Então me retornou o seguinte erro:

```
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://sigep.correios.com.br/sigep/update/AtendeClienteService.wsdl'.
The remote server returned an unexpected response: (407) authenticationrequired.
The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

Para contornar este erro, eu baixei o o XML do WSDL, copiei para o meu IIS local e adicionei o seguinte endereço como Service Reference:

> http://localhost/AtendeClienteService.wsdl

Comment: Vou testar sua solução, caso também sirva para mim eu marco positivo. Obrigado.